# Hive query error java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, amazon-emr

Hello I am executing an Hive query :

```
CREATE TABLE temp_session_orgid as
SELECT
    sorgid.property_num, sorgid.visitid, sorgid.fullvisitorid, sorgid.adate, sorgid.hits_customvariables_customvarvalue as orgid
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *,
            row_number() over (partition by property_num, visitid, fullvisitorid, adate order by hitsid) as rn
        FROM bt_hits_custom_vars
        WHERE hits_customvariables_customvarname = 'orgId'
    ) sorgid
WHERE
    sorgid.rn = 1
;

Hive:2.1.1
EMR:5.3.1
```

where I am getting following error:

> Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
>   java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.process(FileSinkOperator.java:785)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:879)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.process(SelectOperator.java:95)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:879)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FilterOperator.process(FilterOperator.java:126)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:879)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.PTFOperator$PTFInvocation.finishPartition(PTFOperator.java:373)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.PTFOperator.process(PTFOperator.java:122)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:879)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.process(SelectOperator.java:95)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.ReduceRecordSource$GroupIterator.next(ReduceRecordSource.java:348)
>         ... 17 more
>       Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.checkClosed(DFSOutputStream.java:1546)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSOutputSummer.write(FSOutputSummer.java:104)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.write(FSDataOutputStream.java:60)
>         at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat$1.write(HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat.java:87)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.process(FileSinkOperator.java:751)
>         ... 27 more
>       ], TaskAttempt 3 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) :
>   attempt_1501196537592_0020_2_01_000000_3:java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error
>   while processing row (tag=0)
>   {"key":{"reducesinkkey0":"89634781","reducesinkkey1":"1442844353","reducesinkkey2":"5186210141339993001","reducesinkkey3":"20150921","reducesinkkey4":"1"},"value":{"_col1":"CUSTOMER"}}
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:211)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:168)
>         at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:370)
>         at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:73)
>         at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
>         at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
>         at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:37)
>         at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

What is the cause of this error ? What is the solution to resolve this error?

Comment: Post query also and is your hive service running without any errors?

Comment: My hive service is running wothout any errors & following is the query :CREATE TABLE temp_session_orgid as
SELECT
 sorgid.property_num, sorgid.visitid, sorgid.fullvisitorid, sorgid.adate, sorgid.hits_customvariables_customvarvalue as orgid
FROM
 (
  SELECT
   *,
   row_number() over (partition by property_num, visitid, fullvisitorid, adate order by hitsid) as rn
  FROM bt_hits_custom_vars
  WHERE hits_customvariables_customvarname = 'orgId'
 ) sorgid
WHERE
  sorgid.rn = 1
;

Comment: Did you find a solution

Answer (score 2):

use below settings in hive.

```
set hive.auto.convert.join=false;
set hive.vectorized.execution.enabled=false;
set hive.vectorized.execution.reduce.enabled=false;
set hive.merge.cardinality.check=false;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode=500;
set hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask = true;
set hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask.size = 10000000;
set hive.auto.convert.sortmerge.join=true;
```